# Is the "SAP Netweaver Gateway adapter" capable of transforming odata Edm.DateTime into json

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I'm just wondering if the SAP NGW adapter is capable of transforming odata Edm.DateTime into a json/javascript DateTime.

For example... 
When retrieving formation from SAP, the following format is available in the odata document - "name_of_attribute": "/Date(1377561600000)/"
What we expect in json: "name_of_attribute" : "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"

Although I can't find it in the documentation, does anyone know if this feature is implemented in the latest release of IBM MobileFirst foundation platform?

Many thanks!

Br.

Wim

Comment: Development team was pinged about the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversation from EDM to JSON format is not implemented in the NWG adapter. It returns the data it receives from the server directly.